# Make popup appear after hovering overing circle on GeoJson layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using an external GeoJson file (data) to populate a map with dots. What I'd like to do is hover over a circle that reveals a popup and follows the mouse. I'd also like to include a click option for anyone not using a mouse. I've tried different steps, but none work with what I have below:

```
//BUILD MAP
var layer = new L.StamenTileLayer("toner-lite");

var map = new L.Map("map", {
    center: new L.LatLng(28.100, -83.600),
    zoom: 6
});

map.addLayer(layer);

//Load GeoJson
L.geoJson (data, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description + " " + feature.properties.name);    
    },

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "red",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0.6,

        });
    }

}).addTo(map);

var circle = L.circleMarker([28.100, -83.600], 5000).addTo(map);

circle.setStyle({
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
marker.bindPopup("Popup content");
        marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            this.openPopup();
        });
        marker.on('mouseout', function (e) {
            this.closePopup();
        });
```